# Counting the number of a certain letter appears in series of strings in an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, intellij-idea, char

I have an ArrayList that stores notes (strings) in the form of "do the dishes". I have a notes class with a method that is supposed to go through all the notes in the ArrayList and count the number of times a certain letter appears. This is the method I have written so far:

```
public int countNumberOf(String letter) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String note = (notes.get(i));
            for (int j = 0; i < note.length(); i++) {
                String letterTemp = note.substring(i, i);
                if (letterTemp.equalsIgnoreCase(letter)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
        return count;
    }
```

However, when I run the program, I'm getting zero for the number of times the letter "a" appears even though I know it's present in the ArrayList. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure it's (i, i) and not (i, i+1) for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a `String` to a method and doing a `substring`, you can always access and compare the characters, e.g.:

```
public int countNumberOf(char letter) {
...
String letterTemp = note.charAt(i);
if (letter == letterTemp) {
        count++;
}
```

Another example:

```
public static int countOccurrences(String text, char character) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == character) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`note.substring(i, i)` will always return an empty string, so `letterTemp.equalsIgnoreCase(letter)` will always return `false`. You should use `note.substring(i, i+letter.length())`

Although I suggest that you use `char` for comparison, in this kind of task. Mostly for simplicity's sake, and to avoid unecessary intermediate strings. The logic would be the same

Answer (score 1):

Your second for-loop seems incorrect.

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
>     String note = (notes.get(i));
>     for (int j = 0; i < note.length(); i++) {
> ```

Watch out for those index variables `i` and `j`.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int countOfLetter = note.length() - (note.replace(letter,"")).length();
```